# php artisan breeze:install Execution error

Tags: php, laravel, breeze

I am new to Laravel, It's cool that there is no need to write code like how I used to write using the vanilla style instead of using a framework like Laravel.

But I do have a problem with my installation. I'm not sure how to fix it tho. Been trying googling this for a while and feeling stuck.

I tried installing Breeze on my local server, and it works fine. But with my cloud server which running Plesk. it shows an error.

Here is what I already did, I've installed these on my composer

```
composer require laravel/breeze --dev
```

Then I try to install these on command with artisan

```
php artisan breeze:install
```

Which brings the output of these

```
Execution /opt/plesk/php/8.2/bin/php has failed with exit code 1, stdout: Laravel\Prompts\Exceptions\NonInteractiveValidationException Required. at vendor/laravel/prompts/src/Concerns/Interactivity.php:32 28▕ 29▕ $this->validate($default); 30▕ 31▕ if ($this->state === 'error') { ➜ 32▕ throw new NonInteractiveValidationException($this->error); 33▕ } 34▕ 35▕ return $default; 36▕ } +13 vendor frames 14 artisan:35 Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle() , stderr:
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try running the command in non-interactive mode by adding the --no-interaction flag: php artisan breeze:install --no-interaction

Comment: I tried running that code it shows an undefined

Comment: you tried running that command how?  is there a reason you are not doing this locally?

Comment: My Lecturer wants to see the development using a domain with a hosting. In the Plesk server, there's a terminal that can be used to run the commands.

Comment: develop it locally and deploy it to the server

Comment: `NonInteractiveValidationException` in Laravel Breeze installation means there is an issue with non-interactive mode. Breeze might require interaction during installation, which isn't possible on your cloud server with Plesk. Try the following:

1. **Run in Interactive Mode**: Use an interactive terminal to run the `php artisan breeze:install` command.
2. **Environment Check**: Ensure your server environment meets Laravel's requirements.
3. **Permissions**: Verify necessary permissions for running scripts and writing files.
4. **Check Logs**

Answer (score 0):

- Use the --no-interaction Flag
- When running the php artisan breeze:install command, add the --no-interaction flag to skip interactive prompts. This can help in non-interactive environments

```
php artisan breeze:install --no-interaction
```